# Using layered approach for a scratch card game

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am doing a small scratch card game on Android. I have an ImageView placed in the center of the screen and a custom view on top of that. I fill the custom view with a specific color (say green so the ImageView is not shown) and then when a user moves his finger on the screen I want to clear the color from the custom view so that the ImageView is shown from underneath. I saw this thread: [Two layers, but can't show the bottom layer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974682/two-layers-but-cant-show-the-bottom-layer-in-android), but stuck on how he has created the eraseable bitmap, the paint for this bitmap and the paint for the path.
Here's my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/img_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
    <com.example.scratchcard.TouchEventView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the code I am using right now for the TouchEventView:

```
public class TouchEventView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    public TouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // nothing to do 
                break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I expect the pixels of the TouchEventView to go transparent where the finger has moved but that does not happen. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ask a specific question. Put some code, (not your entire file please) and snapshots of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Take a look at the fingerpaint demo in you sdk samples.

Comment: Hi Siddarth I've updated the question as suggested.

Comment: Hi James, it is a little different scenario, I want to clear the color off of the view rather than add any color.

Comment: Which is exactly why you want to look at the fingerpaint demo. There is an erase function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: better yet dont think of it as erasing. think of it as painting transparency.

Comment: you are a super hero! Thanks man that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this project which has 2 layers, as you scratch the top layer, the bottom layer gets revealed. Also the creator gives out a free license!

https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView